# Absolute table header changes it's size

Tags: css, html-table

I want to create menu with table and make its font fit to the window size to the header image when it get smaller get smaller actually be absolute how?

```
<div id="header" style="position:relative;" dir='rtl'>
    <img id='header1' src="header.png" style="position:absolute; width:100%;"/>
    <img id="logo1" src="logo1" style="position:absolute;left:30px;width:20%;"/>
    <img id="logo2" src="logo.png" style="position:absolute;  width:20%; right:30px;"/>
    <center><table dir="rtl" style="position:absolute; width:100%; right:30px;"><tr><td>five</td><td>four</td><td> three</td><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>bla</td><td> seven</td><td>six</td></tr></table></center>
</div>
```

Comment: someone? help ? plead XD

Comment: everytime you use tables a professional web designer dies

Comment: SO what should i do? @omegaiori darling

Comment: Oh...and `<center>` shouldn't be used either as it's been deprecated,

Comment: this is what i get on jsfiddle: http://prntscr.com/3govcb your problem is not very clear.. in any case, if i understood well, text cannot be "elastic", unless you use a js library like fittext.js -> http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: you should clean up a bit your HTML. as @omegaiori says , js will help you. You may want to play around with vw or vh units for font size

Comment: why do you want to use a table?  why not an unordered list?